# mysqldbcompare SELECT command denied to user

Tags: mysql, linux, mysqldump

I am trying to run mysqldbcompare to see the difference between two tables:

```
mysqldbcompare --server1=server1:2016@localhost --server2=server2:2016@localhost user:user --difftype=sql --run-all-tests
```

I get this error. I have already granted all privileges to users.

> ERROR: Query failed. 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'server1'@'localhost' for table 'proc'

Answer (score 2):

You should enable the dbuser to have READ permissions to the proc table.

> The process attempts to perform a SELECT statement on the 'proc'
>   table.  The 'proc' table is a system table which retains the
>   procedures of all users on that mysql instance.  On shared hosting,
>   allowing userA to see the procedures of userB, which would include
>   information about table structure, etc., would be considered breach of
>   security.[All info found here](http://knowledge.3essentials.com/web-hosting/article/990/ERROR-SELECT-command-denied-to-user-user-x-for-table-proc.html)

Or you can use the root user.

Comment: The trouble I ran into was due to the databases being on shared hosting which is discussed in the attached link. It also provides more information about the answer provided by Amin. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Add this to the connection string

```
Use Procedure Bodies =false;
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. Could you explain a bit more about what that does and how it should help?